# Adding subjectAltName to csr using phpseclib

Tags: phpseclib

I am using phpseclib to generate private key, public key and CSR and i just want to be able to include subjectAltName to the Public key and CSR in the process but the documentation is no good. I tried using setDomain but all that does is overides the primary commonName value..

I found this from another post but it doesn't seem to have any effect:
`$x509->setExtension('id-ce-subjectAltName', array('san1.domain.com', 'san2.domain.com'));`

-- UPDATE --

I am step closer, I see the extension for subjectAltName in my certificate but its blank field

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

thanks

Here is some php code..

```html
$altnames = array (
"san1.domain.com",
"san2.domain.com"
);

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->loadX509($x509->saveX509($x509->sign($issuer, $subject)));
$x509->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array('digitalSignature', 'keyEncipherment'));
$x509->setExtension('id-ce-extKeyUsage', array('id-kp-serverAuth', 'id-kp-clientAuth'));
$x509->setExtension("id-ce-subjectAltName", $altnames);
```

Answer (score 0):

phpseclib doesn't currently support subjAltDomain's for CSR's very well. More info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28610388/569976

Comment: I did come across that link but it didnt work for me. Not sure if anyone else has tried it with any success.. No big deal though. Whilst I have your attention do you know how to extract the key size from the CSR and public key? I was searching hard for that but found nothing.

Comment: i found half the answer to my question for adding subAltname to the public key -- actually i believe the solution is in your pastebin http://pastebin.com/acmcXbAg - i tested it and it works perfectly.. seems like the cert has to be resigned but it works. Now just need to know how to add the subaltnames to the csr!